# labels wont show up on d3 force diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a beginner at d3. One of the diagrams I find particularly helpful and fun is the d3 force diagram. I've been playing around with it, but for some reason I've had a lot of trouble with this particular data set. Specifically, I've been trying forever to get the labels to show up on my d3 force diagram, but it just won't work. Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
 .links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}
.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("links.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return 1});

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return 3*d.size;
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

      node.append("svg:title")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}
function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}
function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
</script>
```

thanks so much for your help

edit: here is my links.json

```
{
  "nodes": [
  {"id": "AK","size": "1.414213562"},
  {"id": "AL","size": "1.414213562"},
  {"id": "AR","size": "1.414213562"},
  {"id": "AZ","size": "2.828427125"}],
"links": [
  {"source": "ABC","target": "CO","value": "A"},
  {"source": "ABC","target": "CO","value": "A"},
  {"source": "ABC","target": "CO","value": "A"},
  {"source": "ABC","target": "FL","value": "A"}
}
```

Comment: can you add your links.json ?

Comment: @Dragon_Slayer added, thanks for your help

Comment: json incorrect ? Its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Added Edit below :**

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

graph = {
  "nodes": [
  {"id": "AK","size": "1.414213562"},
  {"id": "AL","size": "1.414213562"},
  {"id": "AR","size": "1.414213562"},
  {"id": "AZ","size": "2.828427125"}],
"links": [
  {"source": "AK","target": "AL","value": "A"},
  {"source": "AL","target": "AZ","value": "A"},
  {"source": "AL","target": "AR","value": "A"},
  {"source": "AZ","target": "AR","value": "A"}]
};
  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return 1});

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return 5;
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

      node.append("svg:title")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id });
 
 var labels = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "label")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("dx", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("font-size",10)
      .text(function(d) { return d.id });

 
  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
   
 labels
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });  
  }

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}
function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}
function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
 .links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}
.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
```

Original answer :

Your json is not "proper". First of all there is no source named ABC or targets named CO or FL.
Source and target values should be an id from the nodes. You cannot link something that is not defined.
 Also you are not using the size and value attribute.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

graph = {
  "nodes": [
  {"id": "AK","size": "1.414213562"},
  {"id": "AL","size": "1.414213562"},
  {"id": "AR","size": "1.414213562"},
  {"id": "AZ","size": "2.828427125"}],
"links": [
  {"source": "AK","target": "AL","value": "A"},
  {"source": "AL","target": "AZ","value": "A"},
  {"source": "AL","target": "AR","value": "A"},
  {"source": "AZ","target": "AR","value": "A"}]
};
  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return 1});

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return 5;
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

      node.append("svg:title")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}
function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}
function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
 .links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}
.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It was actually a careless mistake by me. The data contains somewhat sensitive information, so I couldn't copy it directly. But, in putting dummy values, I completely messed up the question. Sorry about that. Also, if it doesn't trouble you too much, could you tell me how to add labels once the nodes and links are established?

Comment: by label do you mean text attached to node ?

Comment: Yep! That's exactly that I mean

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much~! To edit the text would I just create a label class in css?

Comment: I'm just having one problem now. When I run your code, I cannot fix the size and color like I could in the previous code. Why do you think this is? Thank you again for helping me so much