# d3.js select for drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag

I have a problem with my real-time chart. In this chart there is many rectangles with means chart.

[image]

I want to this rectangles have a drag and drop. Drag function:

```
function dragged(d) {
  var xd = d3.event.x;
  var yd = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this).select("text")
    .attr("x", xd)
    .attr("y", yd);
  d3.select(this).select("rect")
    .attr("x", xd)
    .attr("y", yd - 20);
  line = focus.select("line.bl").attr("x1", xd).attr("y1", yd)
}
```

But whichever I choose the rectangle, It will the first. I know what "select" choose only first element, but how can I select element, which I want?

Comment: Show the part of your code when you add drag event handler on the elements.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7r4tfxd1/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=7r4tfxd1 @MikhailShabrikov

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928869/trying-to-link-object-and-text-when-dragging-in-v4