# D3 force directed graph issue: nodes are stacked at coordinate (0,0)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm making d3 force directed graph, and it works alright
([this is the working version on codepen](https://codepen.io/aeternia/pen/ozVxaG) ) until I try to add labels for the nodes.

To my understanding,    node    has to be wrapped by    'g'     element, but when I try it, all the nodes become stacked it the upper-left corner. I'm very unfamiliar with JavaScript, and obviously am missing something. I would be grateful if anyone could help me to fix my mistake.
I tried solution from a similar topic: [labels wont show up on d3 force diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596775/labels-wont-show-up-on-d3-force-diagram/38598139#38598139)

```js
 var dataURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aeternia-ua/temp1/c50fa778c12c6d355fe08b54cb3f1ce24acfa4e9/graphtest.json";

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-150))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json(dataURL, function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
    simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);

    var link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line");

    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")

    //Setting node radius by group value. If 'group' key doesn't exist, set radius to 8
    .attr("r", function(d) {
            if (d.hasOwnProperty('group')) {
                return d.group * 2;
            } else {
                return 9;
            }
        })
        //Colors by 'group' value
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.group);
        })
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended));

    node.append("svg:title")
        .attr("dx", 12)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.id
        });

    var labels = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("dx", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("font-size", 10)
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.id
        });


    simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(graph.links);
});

function ticked() {

    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y;
        });

    labels
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return d.y;
        });
}

function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
}
```

[Full code on codepen](http://codepen.io/aeternia/pen/qazrgQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the function `ticked()` to inside your `d3.json` callback:

```
d3.json(dataURL, function(error, graph) {
    //...
    function ticked(){
        //...
    };
};
```

Also, change the class of the links from `.links` to `.link`:

```
var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "link")
```

Here is your updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORejme?editors=0110

Answer (score 2):

`link`, `node`, and `labels` are defined locally to the anonymous function in the `d3.json()` call and so are not available from within `ticked()`.